# Trying to return <spans> from a series of loops/maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to break up an inputted string and then iterate through an array of objects to match each part of the string to a series of spellings (you can see the data structure below). However I am just returning `undefined` it seems.

Here is my redux code

```
const wordSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'word',
  initialState: { word: '', preppedWord: '' },
  reducers: {
    [...]
    checkPhonemes(state, action) {
      console.log(decoder.phonemeCheck(state.word))
      state.preppedWord = decoder.phonemeCheck(state.word)
    },
  },
})
```

Here are the relevant functions:

```
export const phonemeCheck = (word) => {
  return phonemeMatcher(word)
}

///map((element) => { /* … */ })
export const phonemeMatcher = (word) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < word.length - i; j++) {
      let chunk = word.substring(i, i + j + 1)
      consonants.map((consonant) => {
        consonant.spellings.map((spelling) => {
          if (chunk === spelling.spelling) {
            console.log(chunk)
            return <span className={'phoneme-class'}>{chunk}</span>
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the data (excerpt)

```
export const consonants = [
  //remember to wrap sounds in / / eg. /s/, /c/
  {
    consonantSound: 's',
    spellings: [
      { spelling: 's', example: 'sun' },
      { spelling: 'ss', example: 'class' },
      { spelling: 'c', example: 'cell' },
      { spelling: 'ce', example: 'voice' },
      { spelling: 'se', example: 'house' },
      { spelling: 'sc', example: 'scent' },
    ],
  },
  {
    consonantSound: 'sh',
    spellings: [
      { spelling: 'sh', example: 'ship' },
      { spelling: 'ch', example: 'machine' },
    ],
  },
  {
    consonantSound: 'ch',
    spellings: [
      { spelling: 'tch', example: 'match' },
      { spelling: 'ch', example: 'chips' },
    ],
  },
[..]
]
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hs3nam5v/9/

Comment: You don't do anything with the results of `consonants.map`. It seems to me like you think that when you do `return` within `consonant.spellings.map` that it somehow will do a `return` for `phonemeMatcher`. It will not. It will only return the value to `consonants.map`, which in turn returns the value to... nothing, because you don't use the value that is returned from `consonants.map`.

Comment: Yes - I think this accurately captures the misunderstanding. So i need a second and thrd return? However now it just stops on the first match - I am trying to build up a series of ``<span>`` to recreate the word, just inside spans so individual styling can be applied

Comment: It seems that `preppedWord` is completely derived from `word`. I'd recommend to call `phonemeCheck` in a (possibly memoized) selector rather than putting this data in the redux store. Also it is not recommended to put JSX/html in the state.

Comment: Instead of doing `return consonants.map`, do something like `arr[i][j] = consonants.map(et cetera...);`, where `arr` is defined outside the outer for-loop and `arr[i]` is defined outside the inner for-loop. Then return `arr` after the for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
export const phonemeCheck = (word) => {
  return phonemeMatcher(word)
}

export const phonemeMatcher = (word) => {
  const phonemes = new Set()
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < word.length - i; j++) {
      let chunk = word.substring(i, i + j + 1)
      consonants.map((consonant) => {
        consonant.spellings.map((spelling) => {
          console.log(spelling.spelling)
          if (chunk === spelling.spelling) {
            phonemes.add(chunk)
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }

  return Array.from(phonemes).map((phoneme) => {
    return <span className={'phoneme-class'}>/{phoneme}/</span>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a set and map on the same so that you don't need to use multiple maps.

You can return something like:

```
   return Array.from(set).map((element) => {
    return <span className={'phoneme-class'}>/{element}/</span>
  }
```